Surface Area: question on formula derivation
I'm following this article to arrive at:
$dS = \sqrt{1 + {f_x(x,y)}^2 + {f_y(x,y)}^2} dx\, dy = \left |\vec{r}_y\times\vec{r}_x\right | \, dx \, dy = \left | \left ({\bf \hat j} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(x_0, y_0) {\bf \hat k} \right ) \times \left ({\bf \hat i} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(x_0, y_0) {\bf \hat k} \right ) \right | dx \,dy$
QUESTION:

How are the following both equal?  What is $\vec r_y$?

$r_y(x_0,y_0)= (\frac {\partial x}{\partial y},\frac {\partial y}{\partial y},\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)) =(0,1,\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)) ={\bf \hat j} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(x_0, y_0) {\bf \hat k}$
I think ${\bf r}(x, y) = a {\bf \hat i} + b {\bf \hat j} + c {\bf \hat k}$.  Is $\vec r_y$ a partial derivative maybe taken just on the last term?

In the derivation on the article, $dx, dy$, seem to get factored out of the $|x \times y|$.  Is there some property of cross product that allows this factoring to the outside?

$\vec {P_0P_1} \approx \vec {P_2P_3} \approx dy \, {\bf \hat j} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(x_0, y_0) \, dy \, {\bf \hat k}$
$\vec {P_0P_2} \approx \vec {P_1P_3} \approx dx \, {\bf \hat i} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(x_0, y_0) \, dx \, {\bf \hat k}$
$dS = |\vec {P_0P_1}| |\vec {P_0P_2}| sin \, \theta = |\vec {P_0P_1} \times \vec {P_0P_2}| \approx \left | \left ({\bf \hat j} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(x_0, y_0) {\bf \hat k} \right ) \times \left ({\bf \hat i} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(x_0, y_0) {\bf \hat k} \right ) \right | dx \,dy$


The surface they consider is of the type $z=f(x,y)$, so the parametrization they used is $r(x,y)=(x,y,f(x,y))$. That's how the got $r_y(x_0,y_0)=(0,1,\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))$. Similarly with $r_x$.

Yes, in fact there is a property of determinants that allows you to do that. If you think the cross product as a determinant, then $dx$ is multiplying just one row, so you can factor it out of the determinant, the same with $dy$.



$\left |\vec{r}_y\times\vec{r}_x\right |= \left |\vec{r_y}(x,y)\times\vec{r_x}(x,y)\right |$ is this change equivalent or perhaps they left the argument out to allow $\vec r(t)$?

Does the subscript of $\vec r$ denote anything of is it just to identify the two different component equations of a vector shown above?

The argument throughout all the first part of the article is the point $(x_0,y_0)$. The subscript is to denote the partial derivative, for instance, $r_y(x_0,y_0)$ denotes the partial derivative of $r$ with respect to $y$ evaluated at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

$r_y(x_0,y_0)= (\frac {\partial x}{\partial y},\frac {\partial y}{\partial y},\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)) =(0,1,\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))$, correct?

Correct! Maybe I would write $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}x$ instead of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$, same with the $y$ component. The notation $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ suggests that $x$ is a function of $y$. Also, and this is just a subtlety, but if you are going to evaluate $r$ at $(x_0,y_0)$, the correct way to express it is to do it in all the coordinates, for example, if $r(x,y)=(x,y^3,x^2y+y^2)$ then $r_y(x_0,y_0)=(0,3y_0^2,x_0^2+2y_0)$.
